# Function definition to count number of words

Tags: c++, file, count

Write a function definition that counts the number of words in a line from your text source.

I tried two different codes and got two different results

```
 countwords()
 {
    ifstream file("notes.txt");
    int count=0;
    char B[80];
    file>>B;
  While (!file.eof())
  {
   cout<<B<<endl;
   file>>B;  
   count++;
   }
}
```

This gives the desired answer.

The other way around :

```
 countwords()
 {
    ifstream file("notes.txt");
    char B[80];
    int count=0;
  While (!file.eof())
  {
   file>>B;
   cout<<B<<endl;
   count++;  
   }
}
```

But this gives an answer which is 1 more than the actual number of words.

Can someone please explain the working of the `eof()` function and the difference in these two loops?

Comment: Do NOT check on `eof()` Just search for why and you'll see. loop on `while(file >> B)`

Comment: I imagine the latter *may* also give a nice screen of gibberish, since `B` content is indeterminate and sending it to `cout` invokes UB.

Comment: Use a [`std::string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) instead of a `char[]`

Comment: [**Read this**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/why-is-iostreameof-inside-a-loop-condition-considered-wrong).

Comment: There is no way any of that code gives any answers. Please post real code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The second version of your answer will always loop one extra time.

Think about this: what happens if `file >> B` fails? You'll still increment `count`.

Also, do not loop on `eof()` because you'll typically loop one too many times. ([Why is iostream::eof inside a loop condition considered wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5605125/27678))

Instead, do the following:

```
while(file >> B)
{
   std::cout << B << std::endl;
   ++count;
}
```

Because your filestream has an implicit conversion to `bool` that checks the state of it, and returns false if it's not `good`.

Comment: Well i have just started files in c++. so please dont mind if i say something wrong.

But how can 'fil>>B'  fail? As soon as it reaches the end, the 'eof()' would be true and the loop will terminate?

Comment: @yasir: Waiting for `eof()` requires that you actually hit the end of file, but what if any of the other error conditions rear their head? File not existing, failed read, or any other `ios_base::failure`? `eof()` will continue returning `false`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not EOF however to see its working Read [this](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/EOF/).

Talking about your code, note the `file>>B;` in first code. Since `file>>B;` fails in last execution of second code, you get one less the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

The reason for outputting 1 more than the actual number of words: In the 2nd version you output B before reading it for the first time. This is a usage of an uninitialized variable and can result in outputting what will look like garbage, or an empty line. Unreliable code.

Also I would suggest using an std::string instead of char[80] as the type for your variable B.